# Flask Error: “Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL”

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to upload an Excel file in my Flask app and I am getting the following error:

> Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

I am not entirely sure why I am getting this error.

Here is my Flask code:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
  #user_file is the name value in input element
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'user_file' in request.files:
    filename = docs.save(request.files['user_file'])
    return filename
  return render_template('upload.html')
```

Here is my upload html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data action ="{{url_for('upload')}}">
      <input type="file" name="user_file">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess you are running Flask not in debug mode. When you changed your files, the changes are not being reflected. Also i don't know if you are using flask-uploads, but i suggest using [Flask-reuploaded](https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded), the maintained version of flask-uploads. No change to code needed, just different package.